# Login form request return error 403 on laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

i just created a new laravel project install the authentication package like i usually does, but when i tried to access login, it return error 403 and said :
"Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

the register is working fine and all other pages that i create are fine too, just the login that has error when i tried to access the login form. i dont understand whats wrong because i did the instalation just like usual and it worked on the last project a week ago

i'm using apache

Comment: "_You don't have permission to access the requested directory_" `/login` is not a directory though. How do you serve your app, Apache, nginx, php artisan serve? What's the URL you are calling, `/login/` or `/login`?

Comment: oh yeah, i access project/public/login. but it has "/" after login when it return the error

Comment: `public` should not appear in your URL, it should be the "DocumentRoot" of your server/vhost. Use `php artisan serve` to serve your app and use the correct URL for login

Comment: now it return not found with a message : "The requested resource /login was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, turns out my partner create a folder name "login" inside public for css folder. i just need to rename it and it work now. i hope this can be a lesson to everyone